# Understanding multithreading from SCJP 6 book

Tags: java, multithreading

The following code is in the SCJP6 book

```java
class ThreadA {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
        b.start();

        synchronized(b) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
                b.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);
        }
    }
}

class ThreadB extends Thread { 
     int total;

     public void run() {
         synchronized(this) {
             for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
                 total += i;
             }
             notify();
         }
     }
 }
```

Won't the previous code cause a deadlock as both thread a and b have a lock on b (in the respective synchronized blocks)?

I am missing something, but not quite sure what it is.

Comment: Have you tried this? is this working? I thnk it wont cost deadlock

Comment: Side note: had there been a deadlock in this situation, the entire wait/notify mechanism would be a complete and utter failre, totally useless.

Comment: Why -1 ? It seems legit to me :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends.

From the documentation of [wait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) method -

> Causes the current thread to wait until another thread invokes the notify() method or the notifyAll() method for this object. In other words, this method behaves exactly as if it simply performs the call wait(0).
>
> The current thread must own this object's monitor. The thread releases
> ownership of this monitor and waits until another thread notifies
> threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either through a
> call to the notify method or the notifyAll method. The thread then
> waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and resumes
> execution.

So, if you consider the two scenarios -

- If `ThreadA` gets the lock on object `b` first, it will wait, resulting in the release of the lock, which will cause `ThreadB` to continue with its work.
- If `ThreadB` gets the lock first, well, it will continue it's work, release the lock, and then `ThreadA` will start. Next, `ThreadA` will wait on the object lock `b`, which may cause it to wait forever.

Comment: A good answer. Short, right to the point. Documentation quote. Makes me believe in SO again ;)

Comment: Although factually true, it misses the point that the main thread might never complete.

Comment: @assylias: Yup, I missed it. Caught that while editing and entering the above two scenarios. Now it's ok.

Comment: @SayemAhmed - you changed the answer to "it depends". The answer should be: **no, the wait/notify mechanism requires synchronization and will not cause a deadlock. The poor code design, however, may.**

Comment: @Dariusz: OP doesn't want to know about whether or not the wait/notify mechanism can cause deadlock. He wants to know whether the current situation can cause deadlock (yes, it's a poor design). The correct answer will be yes, and I missed that on the first pass, but became aware of this when I was editing the answer to write down the different scenarios that may occur here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I missed the point that wait will release the locks.

Answer (score 6):

The likeliest execution is as follows:

- there is a slight delay between `b.start()` and the `run` method being executed
- the main thread therefore manages to acquire the lock on `b` and enters the `synchronized` block
- it then waits on `b` (**which releases the lock**)
- when `run` starts executing, the monitor is available (or will be available fairly shortly) so it can enter the `synchronized` block
- when it's done it notifies `b` that it can stop waiting
- the main thread completes.

However, depending on thread scheduling, it is not impossible that `run` be executed first, in which case the main thread could wait forever on `b.wait()`. For example, if you help that situation by inserting a small `Thread.sleep(100)` right after `b.start()`, you should observe that behaviour.

Bottom line: it is a smelly code that could encounter liveness issues (it is not a deadlock per se since the lock is available).

Comment: Good catch with the execution order error, but you did not actually answer the question.

Comment: @Dariusz What do you mean?

Comment: The question was: "will it cause a deadlock". I think that's the thing OP wanted to know. I know you mentioned that waiting releases the lock, but it's not a straight answer. Still a good answer, I +1'd.